# Distribution of $ Y = X_1 + X_2-n_2 $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that
$ X_1\sim Bin(n_1, 1/2) $ and $X_2\sim Bin(n_2,1/2)$ be independent random variables . Find the distribution of $Y = X_1-X_2+n_2$

Attempt : 
$$ P[Y = X_1-X_2+n_2 ] = \binom{n_2}{x_1-x_2+n_2}*(1/2)^{x_1-x_2+n_2} *(1/2)^{x_1-x_2} \\ 
 =  \binom{n_2}{x_1-x_2+n_2} (1/2)^{n_2} $$

Is this right ? 
It seems wrong since answer is independent of $n_1$ and I hadn't used the fact that both are independent random variables .

Comment: I've edited to correct an apparent inconsistency. Is it OK?

Comment: So the question is flawed, and you should take my interpretation. Besides, $Y$ is already defined as $\operatorname{binom}(n_2,1/2)$, so if the question was really like that it'd be trivial.

Comment: Can you change the question  such that it uses that fact : " Independent " and both $n_1$ and $n_2$  ?

Comment: How ? As My answer is independent of $n_2$ and "independent"  random variables "X" and "Y"

Comment: Keep your working, even though it's wrong. I'll restore my edits and give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are indeed wrong in any case. Here is a much simpler method. $\newcommand{bin}{\operatorname{binom}}$

By comparing pmfs – the expanded pmf of $X_2$ is $P(X_2=k)=\binom{n_2}k\left(\frac12\right)^{n_2}$, while we have the identity $\binom nk=\binom n{n-k}$ – we see that
$$n_2-X_2\sim X_2\sim\bin\left(n_2,\frac12\right)$$
Therefore
$$Y\sim X_1+X_2\sim \bin\left(n_1+n_2,\frac12\right)$$

Comment: @Doraemon You're going too fast. You pulled out the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ from nowhere, and furthermore you're taking the wrong top argument for the binomial coefficient.

Comment: I think in last argument you used the fact that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent .

Comment: @Doraemon It _is_. Read it again, "I have independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$..."

Answer (score 1):

The key point is that if $$X_2 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n_2, p),$$ then $$n_2 - X_2 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n_2, 1-p).$$  The proof is simple.  Since we have $$\Pr[X_2 = x] = \binom{n_2}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n_2 - x},$$ we then have $$\begin{align*}
\Pr[n_2 - X_2 = x] &= \Pr[X_2 = n_2 - x] \\
&= \binom{n_2}{n_2-x} p^{n_2 - x} (1-p)^{n_2 - (n_2 - x)} \\
&= \frac{(n_2)!}{(n_2 - x)! \, (n_2 - (n_2 - x))!} (1-p)^x p^{n_2 - x} \\
&= \binom{n_2}{x} (1-p)^x p^{n_2 - x},
\end{align*}$$
which is the PDF of a binomial distribution with parameters $n_2$ and $1-p$.  Of course, we can use an elementary counting argument to conclude the same, or we could also use the fact that a binomial distribution is the sum of IID Bernoulli variables.

In fact, this latter property is what we can now easily use to complete the answer:  Since $p = 1/2$ for $X_2$, then $n_2 - X_2$ is also binomial with parameter $1 - p = 1/2$, thus $X_1$ is the sum of $n_1$ IID Bernoulli variables and $n_2 - X_2$ is the sum of $n_2$ IID Bernoulli variables, and they **all** share the same parameter $p = 1 - p = 1/2$.  Thus $Y = X_1 + n_2 - X_2$ is the sum of $n_1 + n_2$ IID Bernoulli random variables with $p = 1/2$, thus $$Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n_1 + n_2, 1/2).$$

Comment: Thanks , your Theory part really helped me a lot .